# How to store scraped data in sql database in java

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, web-scraping

I have to fetch the data of shares rates from the website of stock exchange and store it in the SQL database. Currently, I am doing this process through excel.  We fetch the data of website in MS Excel then using macros it creates .csv files and then through procedures we retrieve the data of these .csv files in our sql database.
Now, what am I supposed to do is

1. First of all I would like to know that is it possible to store
   scraped data into oracle SQL database?
2. I want to create a java program which scrapes the data from the
   website.
3. Then Directly store it in the oracle sql database.

I have created a program which scrapes the web page but, not getting the rates. Code is as follows:

```
package connectingurl;

import java.io.*; 
import org.jsoup.*; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element; 
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ConnectingUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc;
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.a.b.abc");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mufap.com.pk/nav_returns_performance.php?tab=01").get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                System.out.println("\nLink: " + links.attr("href"));
                System.out.println("text: " + links.text());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This code only brings the menu buttons translation repeatedly. I want to fetch the rates mentioned on the page. 
As I am new to java so I have so many complications regarding this.

P.S: I am new to stack overflow so kindly brief me the points which I missed.

Comment: I think you'll need to break down your question into pieces since there's more than one. Typically there's just one topic per question. So, I think it's best to focus on getting the correct data from the page and then later take a look at connecting to a database to store the data.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are searching for isn't in a link, so that won't work. I had a quick look at grabbing the data out by XPATH, but the HTML isn't valid XML - so that makes life hard.